# Ternary operation syntax

Tags: c#

```
newViewModel.Notification = "information" ? "information" : "success";
```

Can anybody help me correct the above?

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'
```

If Notification does not equal "information", it should equal "success".

Comment: It's called the conditional operator. Naming things by their arity should be avoided, even if there's currently only one available in C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct usage would be:

```
newViewModel.Notification = newViewModel.Notification == "information" ? "information" : "success";
```

This follows the syntax as [defined here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

Where: "The condition must evaluate to true or false." (i.e. a boolean value)

---

However, there is no point using a ternary if you only want to set it under one condition, consider a single if statement instead:

```
if(newViewModel.Notification != "information")
    newViewModel.Notification = "success";
```

This is also, in my opinion, much easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 4):

The first operand needs to be a boolean:

```
newViewModel.Notification = newViewModel.Notification == "information" ? "information" : "success";
```

However (as Matti Virkkunen suggested), you could use simple `if` statement (especially if you will not have `else` branch)

```
if(newViewModel.Notification == "information")
    newViewModel.Notification = "success";
```

Comment: And how is this any better than an `if`?

Comment: I didn't say that. I am just answering the question.

Comment: -1. I think it's more important to be actully helpful than "just answer the question".

Comment: To be fair, answering the question was helpful. So +1. But I agree an if statement is better.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen That's ludicrous. Just because you'd have used a different construct doesn't mean this is unhelpful. If you feel you have a better alternative post an answer, but downvotes should be kept to answers that are actually of no use to the OP.

Comment: @millimoose: I reverted my downvote because the answer is actually useful now. It wasn't when I saw it.

Answer (score 2):

Your ternary is taking a string, it needs to take a bool as the message is saying, it needs to go like this:

```
boolean ? object : object
```

Do you mean to do one of these?

```
newViewModel.Notification = 
    (something == "information" ? "information" : "success");
```

or

```
newViewModel.Notification = 
    (newViewModel.Notification == "information" ? "information" : "success");
```

---

Note that this isn't a particularly great place to use a ternary, a straight `if` would probably be better.

```
if (newViewModel.Notification != "information")
    newViewModel.Notification = "success"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `string.Equals` is *arguably* more semantic/self documenting:

```
newViewModel.Notification =
    newViewModel.Notification.Equals("information") ? "information" : "success";
```